# JavaScript - Toggle classes based on click event

Tags: javascript

I'm working on improving my JavaScript after using jQuery so much. I'm trying to toggle visibility of a list of elements based on what the user clicks on.

Here is a Code Pen example:
http://codepen.io/sdejaneiro/pen/BjEVBQ?editors=1000

In the example, what I want to do is, when clicking on "Part 1 Item C" (or Part 2 Item C or Part 3 Item) (which has class `series`) I want to show the Sub-items below it (which are contained inside a `ul` list with classes `seriesSet` and `hidden`. I've gotten as far as attaching a click even to each instance of the class `series` but am not sure how to target the correct `seriesSet`. I tried using a forEach attached to each instance of `seriesSet`, but that ended up triggering all the `ul` lists with that class all at once.

I want to try and keep the code as clean as possible, so I avoided adding ids to the `seriesSet` lists, but maybe I do need something like that for JavaScript?

Here is the JavaScript:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

//toggle series lists
document.querySelectorAll('.series').forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //select the correct .seriesSet ul list and remove class "hidden"
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for

`e.target.children[0].classList.toggle("hidden");`

Comment: This answer is correct, just adding a note that if you want to use this in old browsers (Mostly IE9), you'll need to include a [shim or polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#JavaScript_shim_for_other_implementations).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use jQuery:

```
$('.series').click(function () {
   $(this).find('.seriesSet').toogleClass('hidden');
});
```

Edit: Sorry, I haven't read the first sentence... :/

Comment: That's ok :P. If this were a jQuery thing, then that is exactly what I would have done.

Answer (score 0):

Using the firstElementChild as the selector for the ul elements withing the clicked list item element. Then test for the hidden class.

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

//toggle series lists
document.querySelectorAll('.series').forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ch = this.firstElementChild;
    e.preventDefault();
    //select the correct .seriesSet ul list and remove class "hidden"
    if (/hidden/.test(ch.className)) ch.className = 'seriesSet';
    else ch.className = 'seriesSet hidden';
  })
});
```

I would capture the list items text in an element like a span, or an a-tag though, that way you're able to prevent the sub-items from toggling the menu back up.

Comment: What do you mean by putting the list elements in a span? Like this? 
<li><span>text</span></li>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/PZgaLO?editors=0010)

```js
var series = document.querySelectorAll('.series');

for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
  series[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateSub(this);
  })
}

function updateSub(el) {
  for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    if (series[i] == el) {
      el.childNodes[1].classList.toggle('hidden');
    } else {
      series[i].childNodes[1].classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach would be to do something like this :

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.series a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
            var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        } else {
            classList.add('open');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

ul.series li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.series li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.series li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.series li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.series li a:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
}

ul.series li > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '+';
}

ul.series li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul class="series">
  <li><a href="#">Part 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/te366hu2/3/))