# show / hide div can do without jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that is now working, but there's still conflict with other scripts on page that I have no control over... (hosted e-com site with limited access) - is there a way to accomplish this, but with plain javascript?

```html
var $b = jQuery.noConflict(true);

var d = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = d.getUTCDay();
var hour = d.getUTCHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
var status = 'open';

if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0 && hour >= 12 && hour < 22)
    status = 'open';
else
    status = 'closed';

if (status=='open')
    $b('.orderby').show();
else
    $b('.orderby').hide();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show hide divs on click in HTML and CSS without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery)

Comment: what is the conflict?

Comment: @NIKHILRANE - I need it to be timed, not on click. So it's different than what you posted.

Comment: @epascarello - not sure, but it breaks the cart & checkout pages, for which I have limited access, so I cannot change that, I must change this script, since it is what I do have access to.

Comment: if you have a `.hidden` class you can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467207/javascript-toggle-classes-based-on-click-event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have 1 tiny bit of jquery in your code

```
if (status=='open') {
    $b('.orderby').show();
}else{
    $b('.orderby').hide();
}
```

This can be converted to

```
if (status=='open') {
    document.querySelector('.orderby').style.visibility = "visible";
}else{
    document.querySelector('.orderby').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: visibility is different then show/hide, to have the same effect you should use `display: block/none`

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".elementClass");
elem.style.display = (status === 'open') ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `querySelectorAll` to get elements and loop over them and add a class that will set `display: none`.

#### show

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".orderby");
for(var k in el){
  el[k].className = el[k].className.replace("hide", "");
}
```

#### hide

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".orderby");
for(var k in el){
  el[k].className += 'hide';
}
```

Comment: You can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to save on having to string mash.

Comment: @Jamiec I was about to comment on your answer. I had a query, will doing `quertSelectorAll(..).classList += " something"` will add class to all or looping is necessary. Also will check your suggestion

Comment: `classList` is not a string its a DOMTokenList, and has methods like `toggle` - `el[k].classList.toggle("hide")` for example

Comment: Opps. I meant `className`

Comment: `className` is not a property of `NodeList` which is what `querySelectorAll` returns - they hide all this info in the docs you know?

Comment: I think, I'll have to study. Will update it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
if (status=='open') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('orderby')[0].style.display = "block";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('orderby')[0].style.display = "none";
    }
```